# Parsing UUID in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I am trying to get data from the Realm database. I am using NSPredicate. And it was working well. But today I have to get data from Object who has string Id. This Id is in UUID. So when ever I try to get the value using UUID(the String ID), it gives me error like so

> nable to parse the format string "Id == BD1698EE-C57D-4B8D-9D54-1D4403B2136F"'

This is the error statement. Whereas I have the following line in the code.

```
let resultPredicateShoppingListDetail = NSPredicate(format: "Id == \(shoppingListModel.Id)")
```

It does not make sense to me. Why this is happening?

Comment: it is UUID already

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use string interpolation to build a predicate format, it is *very*
difficult to get the necessary quoting correct. As an example, this would work (note the additional
single quotes):

```
let uuid = "BD1698EE-C57D-4B8D-9D54-1D4403B2136F"
print(NSPredicate(format: "id == '\(uuid)'"))
// id == "BD1698EE-C57D-4B8D-9D54-1D4403B2136F"
```

but also fail if the `uuid` string contains a single quote.

Better use the `%@` var arg substitution for strings:

```
let uuid = "BD1698EE-C57D-4B8D-9D54-1D4403B2136F"
print(NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", uuid))
// id == "BD1698EE-C57D-4B8D-9D54-1D4403B2136F"
```

In your case (assuming that `shoppingListModel.Id` is a `String` or `NSString`):

```
let resultPredicateShoppingListDetail = NSPredicate(format: "Id == %@", shoppingListModel.Id)
```

Even better, use the `%K` keypath var arg substitution and the `#keyPath`
compiler directive to insert the correct key path:

```
let resultPredicateShoppingListDetail = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@",
                 #keyPath(ShoppingList.Id), shoppingListModel.Id)
```

For more information about `%K` and `%@` in predicates, see
[“Predicate Format String Syntax”](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the “Predicate Programming Guide.”